# Having trouble with the output of my reversal array

Tags: java, arrays, reverse

Ok so I have my code and everything works great but I'm not seeing why my output gives me `two reversals` instead of the `one`. The last one is correct but the first output for the reversal is a little mixed up.

```
public class ICE17 {

       static //Examine the following program:
       class ArrayProblems {

            public static void main(String[] args) {

                int[] val = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
                int sum = 0; //write code here

                for (int i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
                    sum += val[i];
                 }

                System.out.println("Sum of all numbers = " + sum);
                reverse();
            }
            public static void reverse() {
                int[] val = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
                //int temp=0;
                System.out.println("Original Array: " + val[0] + " " + val[1] + " " + val[2] + " " + val[3]);
                // write code here to reverse the order of the numbers in the array
                for (int i = 0; i < val.length / 2; i++) {

                    int temp = val[i];
                    val[i] = val[val.length - 1 - i];
                    val[val.length - 1 - i] = temp;    
                    System.out.println("Reversed Array: " + val[0] + " " + val[1] + " " + val[2] + " " + val[3]);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your curly brackets!

```
for (int i = 0; i < val.length / 2; i++) {
    int temp = val[i];
    val[i] = val[val.length - 1 - i];
    val[val.length - 1 - i] = temp;

    System.out.println("Reversed Array: " + val[0] + " " + val[1] + " " + val[2] + " " + val[3]);
}
```

As you can see, you are printing out the reversed array each time the for loop runs. 
The reversal isn't finished in the first loop, so it prints out a little funny.

Comment: Ah! Thank you! I must be tired, can't believe I didn't see that!

Answer (score 2):

Erick has answered right for fixing the print issue. You are printing the array within for loop, so it will print it for length/2 times.

Other thing that your reverse method is creating a local array and reversing it. If you really want to reverse the array created in main method then write a function which will take an array as input like below:

```
public class ICE17 {

    public static void reverseArray(int[] val) {
        for (int i = 0; i < val.length / 2; i++) {
            int temp = val[i];
            val[i] = val[val.length - 1 - i];
            val[val.length - 1 - i] = temp;
        }
    }

    public static void printArray(int[] val) {
        for(int i: val) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
        System.out.println("Array before reverse");
        printArray(arr);
        reverseArray(arr);
        System.out.println("Array after reverse");
        printArray(arr);
    }
}
```